# Superagent with absolute url prefix

Tags: node.js, absolute-path, superagent

I've noticed that I'm writing `http://localhost` everytime I want to run a node test with [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent).

```
import superagent from 'superagent';

const request = superagent.agent();
request
  .get('http://localhost/whatever')
  .end((err, res) => { ... });
```

Is there any way of avoiding the `localhost` part?

As far as I've gone is to avoid the request being hardcoded to the host:

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3030';

request
  .get(`${baseUrl}/whatever`)
```

But I still have to carry the `baseUrl` with the agent everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** [superagent-absolute](https://github.com/zurfyx/superagent-absolute) does exactly that.

**Detailed:**

You can create one abstraction layer on top of [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent).

```
function superagentAbsolute(agent) {
  return baseUrl => ({
    get: url => url.startsWith('/') ? agent.get(baseUrl + url) : agent.get(url),
  });
}
```

⬑ That would override the `agent.get` when called with a starting `/`

```
global.request = superagentAbsolute(agent)('http://localhost:3030');
```

Now you would need to do the same for: DELETE, HEAD, PATCH, POST and PUT.

https://github.com/zurfyx/superagent-absolute/blob/master/index.js

```
const OVERRIDE = 'delete,get,head,patch,post,put'.split(',');
const superagentAbsolute = agent => baseUrl => (
  new Proxy(agent, {
    get(target, propertyName) {
      return (...params) => {
        if (OVERRIDE.indexOf(propertyName) !== -1 
            && params.length > 0 
            && typeof params[0] === 'string' 
            && params[0].startsWith('/')) {
          const absoluteUrl = baseUrl + params[0];
          return target[propertyName](absoluteUrl, ...params.slice(1));
        }
        return target[propertyName](...params);
      };
    },
  })
);
```

Or you can simply use [superagent-absolute](https://github.com/zurfyx/superagent-absolute).

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
const superagentAbsolute = require('superagent-absolute');

const agent = superagent.agent();
const request = superagentAbsolute(agent)('http://localhost:3030');

it('should should display "It works!"', (done) => {
  request
    .get('/') // Requests "http://localhost:3030/".
    .end((err, res) => {
      expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
      expect(res.body).to.eql({ msg: 'It works!' });
      done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

While not so recently updated a package as [`superagent-absolute`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467612/1034856), [`superagent-prefix`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-prefix) is officially [recommended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent#plugins), and has the highest adoption as of 2020.

[It is such a simple package](https://github.com/johntron/superagent-prefix/blob/master/index.js) that I would not be concerned with the lack of updates.

Example usage:

```
import superagent from "superagent"
import prefix from "superagent-prefix"

const baseURL = "https://foo.bar/api/"
const client = superagent
  .agent()
  .use(prefix(baseURL))
```

Comment: "superagent.use is not a function". This no longer works

Comment: @JorisMans Fixed. Thanks for the note. Superagent now requires an "agent" to be created explicitly, in order to maintain state for future requests.