# Fetch with absolute url prefix

Tags: node.js, absolute-path, node-fetch

Most of the times I prefix [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) with an `http://localhost` (to make it an absolute url).

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

fetch('http://localhost/whatever')
```

Is there any way of avoiding the `localhost` part, other than simply placing `localhost` in a variable?

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

fetch(`${baseUrl}/whatever`)
```

*Very related to [Superagent with absolute url prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467611/superagent-with-absolute-url-prefix)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** [fetch-absolute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-absolute) does exactly that.

**Detailed:**

You can create one abstraction layer on top of [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
function fetchAbsolute(fetch) {
  return baseUrl => (url, ...otherParams) => url.startsWith('/') ? fetch(baseUrl + url, ...otherParams) : fetch(url, ...otherParams)
}
```

Or you can simply use [fetch-absolute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-absolute).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fetchAbsolute = require('fetch-absolute');

const fetchApi = fetchAbsolute(fetch)('http://localhost:3030');

it('should should display "It works!"', async () => {
  const response = await fetchApi('/');
  const json = await response.json();
  expect(json).to.eql({ msg: 'It works!' });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `fetch` function:

```
import origFetch from 'node-fetch';

const fetch = (url, ...params) => {
  if (url.startsWith('/')) return origFetch('http://localhost' + url, ...params)
  else return origFetch(url, ...params);
}
```

The other answer creates a function that returns a function that returns a function--that's not necessary; you just need to return a function.

```
function fetchAbsolute(fetch, base_url) {
  return (url, ...params) => {
    if (url.startsWith('/')) return fetch(base_url + url, ...params)
    else return fetch(url, ...params);
  }
}

const fetch = fetchAbsolute(origFetch, 'http://localhost');
```