# Change base URL for fetching data in ASP.NET Core 3 with React

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with the React template and so far everything works fine.

But to test my frontend changes locally without always pushing to the server (on which the data is stored), I'm trying to figure out if and how I can change the base-URL my fetch requests go to. For example my login fetch request looks like the following:

```
fetch('api/authentication/login', requestOptions).then(..)
```

Which then defaults to

```
localhost:5000/api/authentication/login
```

Is there a way I can replace the base-URL with my server-URL to work with the data on the server? 
I've already tried changing

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    rootElement
);
```

to

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename={"http://my-server-url.com"}>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    rootElement
);
```

Unfortunately that changed nothing but I can't find a different thing to try.

Is there a way to get this running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch with absolute url prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470822/fetch-with-absolute-url-prefix)

Comment: You have to do something like `fetch(YOUR_HOST + 'api/authentication/login', ...)`

Comment: @norbitrial Thank you for that suggestion but unfortunately not.

Comment: @MjZax Ah, okay. Thank you!

Comment: @LukasKöhler Make sure that you enable `CORS` in the server for `localhost`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the proxy function of react's development server for this.

You can add the following proxy definition to your `package.json` file:

```
"proxy": "http://my-server-url.com",
```

And then (from with the ClientApp folder) start the React app using

```
> npm start
```

For more documentation of the proxy features, see [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).